# Are there any formal theories that are not axiomatic?

Tags: axioms, formal-systems

Are there any formal theories that are not axiomatic? Could you give me some examples?

Comment: Not in first-order predicate calculus, thogh the axioms may be specified in a way that does not permit verifying whether a sentence is an axiom. For example one may choose to look at the theory determined by all sentences true in the natural numbers.